# Retrieve information on experimental phenotypes recorded in eSet and ExpressionSet-derived classes

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I want to assign `cmoic.kirp$clust.res$clust` as the `phenoData` of the `bulk.eset` using [Biobase](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Biobase/versions/2.32.0/topics/phenoData). The `bulk.eset` is an ExpressionSet of `bulk.kirp`.

```
library(Biobase)

bulk.eset <- new("ExpressionSet", exprs=as.matrix(bulk.kirp))
phenoData(bulk.eset) <- cmoic.kirp$clust.res$clust
```

Traceback:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘phenoData<-’ for signature ‘"ExpressionSet", "character"’
```

Data:

```
> dput(bulk.kirp)
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 6.35598354101006, 
14.3511850042327, 10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255, 9.44832324553207, 
9.78880184184623, 10.3776687573505, 11.16757118884, 9.53872845925388
), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 6.93597002271109, 12.4136523086721, 
11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252, 9.9623840324273, 10.3398477765017, 
10.3103072842012, 11.1287210937383, 9.12552428380532), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 
7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 9.96839262629172, 9.87305770150294, 
9.75535162798677, 10.238532641469, 9.94050095178643, 11.0690397931313, 
9.18120494347434), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 6.89258167250936, 
13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992, 10.0652444551968, 
10.1079093507719, 11.2050505161752, 11.6645692817891, 9.14131578384568
), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(5.13719199914349, 6.92859654071157, 12.0367193976262, 
10.8202555636581, 10.3262700402849, 9.91216810777653, 10.0653680664815, 
10.5954686012028, 11.2355920880251, 9.10909645558853), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A = c(6.95117512427229, 
7.25014205824679, 10.9656928148969, 10.5991523452113, 10.4556415168452, 
9.46537845450025, 10.0139441477751, 9.28408724134641, 11.4833270722276, 
9.49617650025352), TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A = c(3.61712213221935, 7.92111077839189, 
11.9975977242282, 9.91379851626213, 9.95999222715916, 9.90779350021794, 
10.3997246047534, 11.7402171909708, 11.7246448152361, 9.75167259046219
), TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A = c(3.15639661659767, 8.66937017282105, 10.9506421354115, 
10.8015070949819, 9.51027580369917, 10.0114476969219, 10.1410206692489, 
10.9093204661635, 11.1601119970792, 9.35889972298825), TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A = c(8.20162111992077, 
5.73826794012289, 12.7954861179578, 10.0094938620897, 9.93400880935778, 
9.75330735360058, 9.74081003982032, 10.7382235152475, 11.6720072357516, 
8.44494819471576), TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A = c(6.26475409489153, 6.39123499553712, 
12.8198023802381, 11.7916439373724, 9.53606689182685, 10.3591574288036, 
10.0630462305102, 10.2195932783632, 11.455724780085, 8.42239448735832
)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", "A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS", "AACS", 
"AAGAB", "AAK1", "AAMP", "AARS2"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(cmoic.kirp$clust.res$clust[1:10])
c("2a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1a", "1b", "2b", "2b", "2a", "1a")
```

Comment: phenoData should be "An optional AnnotatedDataFrame containing information about each sample. The number of rows in phenoData must match the number of columns in assayData. Row names of phenoData must match column names of the matrix / matricies in assayData."